# Change Permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

проблема такова есть сайт , в нем категории , ссылка выглядит таким site.ru/category-/category-b/category-c/postname, нужно чтобы она была вида site.ru/category/postname 
Пробовал через функцию

```
add_filter( 'category_link', 'wpse7807_category_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse7807_category_link( $catlink, $category_id )
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $catlink = $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct();

if ( empty( $catlink ) ) {
    $catlink = home_url('?cat=' . $category_id);
} else {
    $category = &get_category( $category_id );
    $category_nicename = $category->slug;

    $catlink = str_replace( '%category%', $category_nicename, $catlink );
    $catlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $catlink, 'category' ) );
}
return $catlink;
```

Так же пробовал через custom permalinks 0 успехов

```
function my_custom_post_kursi() {



$args = array(
      'labels'        => $labels,
      'description'   => 'Пользовательский тип записей Учителя и уроки',
      'public'        => true,
      'menu_position' => 1,
      'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail', 'kursi-category','post-formats'),
      'has_archive'   => true,
   );
   register_post_type( 'kursi', $args );   
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_kursi' );
```

Буду благодарен за помощь, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Админка -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Custom: `/%category%/%postname%/`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [тут](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA) высказан консёрн по поводу такой формы ссылки.

[Тут](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/) офдока как пользовать пермалинки